# SQL query select and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables:

Table "panels":

```
+--------+----------+---+
| id_panel | name_panel |
+-----------------------+
|    1   | Some name    |
|    2   | Other name   |
+--------+--------------+
```

Table "panel_power":

```
+--------+----------+----+
| id_panel | panel_power |
+------------------------+
|    1   |      300W     |
|    1   |      500W     |
|    2   |      450W     |
|    2   |      300W     |
+--------+---------------+
```

I need to output panel names with all their associated powers.

Like:

```
Some panel name: 300W, 500W
Other name: 450W, 300W
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can combine group concat and concat to get your result in one column, although this is not recommended if you plan on storing the data inside a table like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.name_panel, 
              ': ', 
              GROUP_CONCAT(pp.panel_power ORDER BY pp.panel_power SEPARATOR ', ')
             ) as "Provided Power"
FROM panels p
JOIN panel_powers pp ON p.id_panel = pp.id_panel
GROUP BY p.name_panel
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b7f6/2)

As a side note, if you are planning on putting this data in a list on a webpage or something like that I would recommend you pull out the id associated to the name panel and have that as a data-id item on your list.. that way you can easily pull it out incase you need to hit the server... if you dont then you would have to try and parse out the name_panel to figure out where it belongs

Comment: Thanks for the solution! What would be a recommended solution?

Comment: @Leonajs well it all depends on what you are doing... if you are pulling the data out to display it a certain way then this will be fine.. however, if you are pulling it out like this to store in a table then thats really bad.. the design would be bad.. I wasn't really clear when I said it was not recommended let me update :) .. +1 reciprocated, thanks

Comment: @Leonajs I just edited with a note about putting it on a webpage and how I would go about doing it if you want me to explain more then i can :)

Comment: thank you for explanation! I need this just to display an html table with this values, so it would be okay. Just curious, how would you insert new panel and random number of it's powers in a single insert statement?

Comment: @Leonajs if you want something like that I'll need to see some sample data with like 5 records and the number of random powers you want to insert (with expected results).. if you do that I can write up a query

Comment: I want to make form in which user insert name of the panel and all powers that panel has. I would have at least two inputs: "Name of the panel" and "Power of the panel". User would add as many power inputs as they like. When they press a button query is ran which inserts name of the panel in "panels" table and it's powers to "panel_power" table with associated panel id.

Comment: @Leonajs how do you know what id to use? is it auto incremented on the panels table?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for forgetting that info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62042/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-leonajs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `group_concat()` function:

```
select p.name_panel, group_concat(pp.panel_power separator ', ') as powers
from panels p join
     panel_powers pp
     on pp.id_panel = p.id
group by p.name_panel;
```